# SQL prepared innerjoin not working

Tags: mysql, sql, qt

I'm developing a program with qt which has this sql code, the logic of the code is that, I need to get some information where any of the introduced fields are correct. the problem is that one of the fields i'm trying to get `nombre.padres` is in another table `padres` and the main table where the information comes is `usuarios` so the value in `usuarios` is `something@something.com` and in `padres` the value `something@something.com` is linked with the text field i want to get in this case `nombre` (`nombre.padres`).

The code I elaborated is this one:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT usuarios.id, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.curso, usuarios.grupo, usuarios.alergias, padres.nombre"
    "FROM usuarios INNER JOIN padres ON usuarios.idmail = padres.email WHERE (padres.nombre=:apellidointro OR"
    " usuarios.nombre=:nombreintro OR usuarios.id=:idintro OR usuarios.curso=:cursointro OR usuarios.grupo=:grupointro "
    "OR usuarios.alergias=:alergiasintro)");
query.bindValue(":nombreintro", ui->lineEdit_3->text());
query.bindValue(":apellidointro", ui->lineEdit_4->text());
query.bindValue(":idintro", ui->lineEdit_5->text());
query.bindValue(":cursointro", ui->comboBox_2->currentText());
query.bindValue(":grupointro", ui->comboBox->currentText());
query.bindValue(":alergiasintro", ui->lineEdit_6->text());
query.exec();
```

But is giving me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN padres ON usuarios.idmail = padres.email WHERE (padres.nombre='' OR u' at line 1 QMYSQL: Unable to execute query

In both tables there's a column called `nombre` that's why we have `nombre.usuarios` which is allright and `nombre.padres` which is causing me the problem.

Summing up I want to get the linked name to `something@something` from the table `padres` when the user inputs `nombre.padres` but with that query I also want to get multiple information from the `usuarios` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print out the query that you are running, you will see that it starts with:

```
SELECT usuarios.id, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.curso, usuarios.grupo, usuarios.alergias, padres.nombreFROM usuarios
```

That is obviously syntactically incorrect (scroll over to see the `FROM`).

Learn how to do some basic debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are correct. Some politeness would be appreciated :)